# Is there a compact way of deleting keys in a nested dictionary in Python 3.9.2?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to delete specific keys in a python dict. Here is my code below:

```
for skin_name in data:
    del data[skin_name]["bitskins"], data[skin_name]["lootfarm"]
    del data[skin_name]["csgotm"], data[skin_name]["csmoney"]
    del data[skin_name]["skinport"], data[skin_name]["csgotrader"]
    del data[skin_name]["csgoempire"], data[skin_name]["swapgg"]
    del data[skin_name]["csgoexo"], data[skin_name]["buff163"]
```

Here is the JSON that I am loading in as a python dict using the json module.

```
{"\u2605 M9 Bayonet | Damascus Steel (Factory New)": {"steam": {"last_90d": 308.19, "last_30d": 321.46, "last_7d": 335.23, "last_24h": 327.18}, "bitskins": {"price": "332.85", "instant_sale_price": "133.14"}, "lootfarm": 366.87, "csgotm": "283.815", "csmoney": {"price": 356.91}, "skinport": {"suggested_price": 252.46, "steam_price": 0, "instant_price": 0, "starting_at": null}, "csgotrader": {"price": 340.94}, "csgoempire": 222.3, "swapgg": 334.69, "csgoexo": 338.23, "buff163": {"starting_at": {"price": 261.75}, "highest_order": {"price": 241.88}}}
```

The output is the following:

```
{"\u2605 M9 Bayonet | Damascus Steel (Factory New)": {"steam": {"last_90d": 308.19, "last_30d": 321.46, "last_7d": 335.23, "last_24h": 327.18}}
```

It works but it's not very compact code-wise. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it the other way around, just make a new dict with data that you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
data = {"\u2605 M9 Bayonet | Damascus Steel (Factory New)": {"steam": {"last_90d": 308.19, "last_30d": 321.46, "last_7d": 335.23, "last_24h": 327.18}, "bitskins": {"price": "332.85", "instant_sale_price": "133.14"}, "lootfarm": 366.87, "csgotm": "283.815", "csmoney": {"price": 356.91}, "skinport": {"suggested_price": 252.46, "steam_price": 0, "instant_price": 0, "starting_at": "null"}, "csgotrader": {"price": 340.94}, "csgoempire": 222.3, "swapgg": 334.69, "csgoexo": 338.23, "buff163": {"starting_at": {"price": 261.75}, "highest_order": {"price": 241.88}}}}
new_data=  {}

for skin_name in data:
    new_data[skin_name] = data[skin_name]['steam']
    
print(new_data)
```

However, then you lose the "steam" tag.